Next.js failing to apply font to text
I am starting a new project with NextJS (version 14.2.13). I created the project using create-next-app, then I have imported two fonts from google fonts using the following code:
./app/fonts.ts
import { Montserrat, Open_Sans } from 'next/font/google'

export const montserrat = Montserrat({
    subsets: ['latin'],
    variable: '--font-montserrat',
    display: 'swap',
});

export const open_sans = Open_Sans({
    subsets: ['latin'],
    variable: '--font-open-sans',
    display: 'swap',
});

Following the official documentation I imported the fonts and added them to the <body> tag in my root layout:
.app/layout.tsx
import {montserrat, open_sans} from './fonts'
import "./globals.css";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${montserrat.variable} ${open_sans.variable} antialiased`}>
          {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

However, something does not work.

When applying the font to an element, the font does not get applied:

.app/page.tsx
import {montserrat} from "./fonts";


export default function Home() {
  return (
      <>
          <h1 className={`${montserrat.className}`}>Hello World</h1>
      </>
  );
}


When defining in the global stylesheet, the variables do not exist. this throws an eslint warning in the IDE and the browser devtools return that the variable is not defined upon inspection.

.app/globals.css
h1 {
  font-family: var(--font-open-sans);
}

h6 {
  font-family: var(--font-montserrat);
}

Why are my fonts not getting applied? I will add that I have been through the official documentation, but it is lacking at best even when followed to the letter.
Any help will be much appreciated.
Edit:
I am adding my config files, just in case they provide any insight
tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./app",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./app/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

tailwind.config.ts
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";
const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        background: "var(--background)",
        foreground: "var(--foreground)",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
export default config;


I had the same issue where the CSS variables weren't showing up in the browser's computed styles, even though everything seemed set up correctly. After spending hours troubleshooting, I discovered that the problem was caused by caching.
To fix this, follow these steps:
Delete the .next folder to clear the Next.js cache. You can do this by running the following command in your terminal:
rm -rf .next
Restart your Next.js development server:
npm run dev
or if you’re using yarn:
yarn dev
Hard refresh your browser to ensure it's not using cached files. You can do this by opening your browser's developer tools, going to the Network tab, checking "Disable cache," and then pressing Ctrl + Shift + R (or Cmd + Shift + R on Mac) to hard refresh the page.
After doing this, the CSS variables were correctly applied, and everything worked as expected. Hopefully, this helps!

This worked, thanks!

How did you find this out?
